# OCaml function format_of_string is not working as expected

Tags: ocaml

I want to write a function that accepts a pair of strings and convert the second element into a format. I thought I could use the `format_of_string` function, but it seems that is doesn't work. This is a simplified version:

```
let pp fmt (e:string * string) = 
  let msg = format_of_string (snd e) in Format.fprintf fmt ("  - "^^msg^^"@.");;
                             ^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
     ('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f) format6
```

Is there a way to make my function accept a pair of strings ?

Comment: You should read the bug report at http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5591

Comment: Indeed ! This gives a solution which is to use `Scanf.format_from_string`. Many thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer my own question but I found the solution thanks to @Pascal Cuoq in the comments above.

The problem is that the compiler is able to convert a string into a format only if it is able to analyze it in order to compute the format type. That is why `format_of_string` is only working on known strings. So a first solution of the problem above would be to convert the string before calling the function, when it is known, but it is not a real answer to the question.

The best solution is to use `Scanf.format_from_string`:

```
val format_from_string : string ->
   ('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f) format6 -> ('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f) format6
```

where is second argument has the same type than the intended format. So for instance, in the example above, because the string souldn't include any `%` argument, it would be :

```
let pp fmt (e:string * string) = 
  let msg = Scanf.format_from_string (snd e) "" in 
    Format.fprintf fmt ("  - "^^msg^^"@.");;
```

Then calling this function is correct only which a string with no `%` argument:

```
# Format.printf "%a" pp ("", "abc");;
- abc
- : unit = ()
```

But it raises an exception otherwise:

```
# Format.printf "%a" pp ("", "abc%d");;
Exception:
Scanf.Scan_failure "format read 'abc%d' does not match specification ''".
```

Answer (score 3):

Counterintuitively, `format_of_string` does *not* convert a `string` into a format (that is not possible to do in a way that is guaranteed to work, because format types are type-checked at compile time, but the content of the string is not known at compile time; `Scanf.format_from_string` checks it at runtime).

Rather, its type is `val format_of_string : ('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f) format6 -> ('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f) format6` -- it takes a format and returns a format, which means it is essentially **an identity function on formats**.

What's the use of such a function? Unusually for expressions in OCaml, string literals in OCaml are "overloaded". They can be either a string type or a format type. Most of the time, it's inferred as a string type. But if you use it in a context that expects a format type, e.g. an argument to `Printf.printf`, the compiler infers it as a format type. But what about if you use it to initialize a variable? The compiler "defaults" to a string type. However, there may be cases when you want to initialize a variable of format type. You can't easily use a type annotation, because formats have really complicated types and you don't want to have to specify it explicitly. Instead, you can pass the string literal through `format_of_string`, which "forces" the compiler to infer it as a format type, but otherwise returns the value unchanged.

P.S. would it be possible for you to take a format instead of a string in the parameter?

Comment: Yes, my function could have taken a format, an that was my fist solution but using Scanf.format_from_string is a better one since it is a lot cleaner in my case (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot take a format as argument and catenate it with other bits of strings and use that as an format: the type system does not allow to express this.

Just think of the case where `"  - "` would have been `"%"`. It is a different example, but it has the same type, so it must be accepted or rejected with the same mechanisms.

Does the line below do what you originally intended?

```
let pp fmt f x = Format.printf fmt "  - %a@." f x ;;
```

Comment: I am not sure because what I want is just to be able to use `@.` and `@ ` in my string. But is is working if I call `format_of_string` on my original string, before calling the function. It is less clean, but working. Thanks anyway.